# Design patterns - how to use it in real case

Tags: design-patterns

I have  some business requirements which sound something like this: 

Find the data in the HR Infotypes that meet the criteria (... listed criteria...), 

For every found data (record) send e-mail to given recipients with the desired text.

For now I've got few sets of criteria to find specific data, but I know that in the future there will be another sets. 

I've decided to build the solution where every set of criteria and settings for messages would be a single class - a SearchAgent or something:

```
public abstract AbstractSearchAgent {
    public run(){...}
    public get_results() {...}
    public send_info() {...}
}
```

first question: is the concept correct?

I also wanted to design application where the main app will be implemented once. when i get the new criteria of searching the data, I only add another child class and the rest will be the same:

```
public class myApp {
    private AbstractSearchAgent searchagent; 

    public static void main() {  
      //for each existing implementation of abstractSearchAgent
      //get instance into searchagent
      //and execute its methods:
      // e.g. 
        searchagent->run();
        searchagent->send_info();
      //
      // if i wanted to do something else with the result
        result = searchagent->get_results();
}
```

second question: how to do it? :)

I thought of using the abstract factory or builder pattern but I don't know which pattern will be proper for this situation and how to build it?

Could anyone help me to decide which way is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this sounds like a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), which is perfectly usable for this kind of job. You are right that you can use a Factory to create the desired search agent.

To improve long term maintainability of your solution, you may consider implementing your search agents as [Composites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) of basic criteria, thus making individual criteria more reusable. This is best when the search criteria can be complex logical expressions, and especially if these include NOT / OR operators, e.g. *"name does not start with 'M' and (age is less than 30 or age is greater than 50)"*. The implementation of this as a Composite hierarchy could look something like this:

- `AndCriteria`

  - `NotCriteria`

    - `NameCriteria`
  - `OrCriteria`

    - `AgeCriteria`
    - `AgeCriteria`

An alternative to this would be [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). This is adequate if the search criteria can be performed in a linear fashion, such as *"name starts with 'M' and age is less than 30 and gender is female"*. This could be implemented as a sequence of Decorators like this:

```
NameFilter -> AgeFilter -> GenderFilter
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. The Strategy Pattern is what I exactly needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Also look into Specification (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). It complements Peter's answer.

Specification still uses Strategy and Composite, but it's specifically geared toward the kind of problem you're trying to solve.

I've used it several times. I even wrote a small domain specific language (using Interpreter) around my specification, so I could assemble the specification composites via a specification language rather than building them in code. While my language didn't look anything like SQL, it has the same conceptual feel to it.